# ImportError: cannot import name secure_dumps

Tags: web2py, data-access-layer, bottle

I'm trying to use a standalone version of web2py's DAL.  I have looked at a couple other posts ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15512342/standalone-use-of-dal-in-web2py) and the link referenced therein) but still haven't been able to solve the problem.  What I have done is copied the gluon folder from the web2py directory into my diretory, and then I do an import statement such as:

```
from gluon import DAL, Field
```

which causes the following error:

```
  File "/home/ec2-user/myproject/gluon/globals.py", line 26, in <module>
    from gluon.utils import web2py_uuid, secure_dumps, secure_loads ImportError: cannot import name secure_dumps
```

I've checked that utils.py exists in the gluons folder and the secure_dumps function is defined therein.  Appreciate if anyone can provide some advice on how to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem was to use `gluino` instead of `gluon`.  `gluino` is a port of web2py to Bottle and other web frameworks and can be downloaded [here](https://github.com/mdipierro/gluino).