# How to import standalone web2py gluon DAL in pyCharm project

Tags: python, pycharm, web2py

I'm new to python, web2py, and pyCharm, but have had success creating small projects in both web2py and pyCharm. I'm trying to write a fairly simple project in web2py, but would like to develop/debug core functions in pyCharm before moving to a web2py environment.

I'm doing this on a Mac running El Capitan 10.11.4, pyCharm Professional 2016.1.2, and the latest install of web2py source installed in my user directory "~/web2py"

I'm running into a basic problem of not being able to import DAL from gluon. The error I get is:

```
File "/Users/zabgay/Documents/GitHub/untitled/import_gluon.py", line 8, in <module>
    from gluon import DAL
ImportError: No module named gluon
```

So far I've created a "pure python" project in pyCharm Professional with one python file containing the following code:

```
import sys
print (sys.path)

sys.path.insert(1, "~/web2py/gluon")
sys.path.insert(1, "~/web2py")

print (sys.path)
from gluon import DAL
db = DAL('sqlite://storage.sqlite')
```

The sys.path variable printed out in the second print statement is:

```
['/Users/zabgay/Documents/GitHub/untitled',    '/Library/Frameworks/SQLite3.framework/Versions/B/Python/2.7', '/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3/Python/2.7', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-override', '/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.11/Python/2.7/site-packages', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.15.1-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Sys-1.0-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.0-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Frameworks/cairo.framework/Versions/1/Python/2.7', '/Users/zabgay/Documents/GitHub/untitled', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
```

I've confirmed that ~/web2py/gluon exists and is populated with files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use web2py's DAL outside the framework you need to install it as a standalone package.

```
pip install pyDAL
```

Instead of `gluon` you use:

```
from pydal import DAL
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks @cdonts, it did work. I had to work out that I have two python installations on my machine and initially I was installing into the wrong one, but once I got that figured out it worked like a charm.

Comment: some additional info at similar to question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15512342/standalone-use-of-dal-in-web2py